# How can I configure HFSS to analyze in frequency sweep?

Tags: frequency, gain

I'm trying to generate a plot Gain(dB) vs Freq(MHz) with HFSS. I do know that it can be obtained clicking to "Create Far Field Report->Rectangular Plot" then select Phi and Theta, and all frequencies. The adaptive solution of my model is 890 MHz and I would like to analyze the frequency range 800-1000MHz. I have tried to modify the properties of the Sweep in all three options Interpolating, Fast and Discrete. For sure, something I'm doing wrong because after the analysis (8 hours in Discrete), still I cannot select all frequencies from 800 to 1000 MHz in steps of 1 MHz and only appears the resonant one 890 MHz. See figure. What I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a frequency sweep to your Solution Setup. Go to the Project Manager area, right click the Solution Setup you want to make analyze several frequencies and select Add Frequency Sweep...

The next time you run the Solution Setup, all frequencies will be investigated.

Answer (score 0):

You might have already found a solution to this question. For anyone else still facing this problem, the solution data of the frequency sweep can be accessed only when the right solution is selected in the context panel as shown below

[image]

If the solution corresponding to the *AdaptivePass* is selected as shown in the OP, data at only one frequency will be available for plotting. This frequency is the solution frequency that is defined in the solution setup. HFSS performs adaptive mesh refinement at this frequency before performing the frequency sweep.